# How to get the MID of all compound value types from Freebase data dump

Tags: freebase

I want to process all the triples with compound value types(CVT). Since the Freebase website is shut down, it's hard find docs.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more about what you're trying to do? CVTs aren't very useful without a fair bit of additional processing, so understanding what you want to do with them might help point to a simpler solution.

Comment: Since some fact like 'A starred as character B in movie C' is described with three triples in freebase:  (A, 'starring',CVT) (CVT, 'character', B) (CVT, 'movie', C). I want to build an Q&A algorithm which can use a single triple to answer questions. So I want process facts like this to  (A, ’movie’, C) and (A, ’character’, B). Then I can use the object of these processed triple to answer question like 'Which character did A played in movie C'